# Aviary IOS strange behavior - adding some toolbar or view which shifts other views (Dynamically framed view) layout top

Tags: iphone, ios, aviary

I have integrated Aviary SDK for IPhone app properly and works fine. Only design issue I am facing is as described below -
When the PhotoEditor is opened for the first time it adds some toolbar strip / view to other views when I navigate to them. If I navigate to other views before the editor is opened for first time them all the views displayed correct.

**Before opening Aviary PhotoEditor - NO white bar at bottom**
[image: Before opening Aviary PhotoEditor]

**After opening Aviary PhotoEditor - There is white bar at bottom**
[image]

Did anybody got this issue or have any idea about this??

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the iOS 6 SDK, then you must include the following line in your editor's customization code:

`[AFPhotoEditorCustomization setUsingIOS6SDK:YES];`